# Launch "App Shortcuts" from outside of app

Tags: macos

By default OSX gives you the ability to create 'App Shortcuts' and this works great however it appears you need to have the app open in order for the shortcut to work, is there any way to create an 'App Shortcut' or something that accomplishes the same thing but is able to start from outside the app itself.

Example
I create an 'App Shortcut' for App 1, but I want to be able to execute that shortcut within another app let's say Google Chrome or some other app.

Thanks in advance.

Reference: System Preferences -> Keyboard -> App Shortcuts (this is what I'm referring to).

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. [One of the intended purposes of these sorts of shortcuts is to let you make a shortcut that takes priority over a "global shortcut" that uses the same keyboard input](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp2271/mac). What you are asking for is to make a shortcut that's intended to circumvent global shortcuts in to a global shortcut - a clear contradiction.

Comment: This is kind of half right. Basically a shortcut key will only act on the **frontmost** app, so that's why it cannot be done. You can make a global shortcut, which will work in any app that has that menu item, but it will still only act on the frontmost app, the one with its name in the top left corner.